# Rotation in $3D$ with $Z$-Coordinate

Tags: matrices, vectors, 3d, rotations

I have a given $3D$ vector$(x,y,z)$ and I want to perform an rotation in $x$ and in $y$ for a $3D$ program to calculate the cameras position. I already found this website : https://open.gl/transformations
Where the matrix operation is explained. But when I calculate it, **my $z$ seems to be wrong...**

Formels :

*angleX - Rotation $X$

angleY - Rotation $Y$

$x$ - Vector $x$

$y$ - Vector $y$

$z$ - Vector $z$*

z=( sin( angleX ) ⋅ y + cos( angleX ) ⋅ z ) + ( − sin( angleY ) ⋅ x + cos( angleY ) ⋅ z )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply first the rotation around $X$ you get:
$$x_1=x\\y_1=\cos(angleX)y-\sin(angleX)z\\z_1=\sin(angleX)y+\cos(angleX)z$$
Then you apply rotation around $Y$ on $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ to get:
$$x_2=\cos(angleY)x_1+\sin(angleY)z_1\\y_2=y_1\\z_2=-\sin(angleY)x_1+\cos(angleY)z_1$$ By combining these equations you get $z_2=-\sin(angleY)x+\cos(angleY)[\sin(angleX)y+\cos(angleX)z]$

Comment: That sounds fine ! But what should the operator between these equations be ? Plus or minus ?

Comment: You replace $x_1$ from the first equation and $z_1$ from the third into the sixth. If you want to use matrices, you use matrix multiplication in reverse order $R_yRx$

Comment: I dont use a real vector, x1 and y1 and z1 are all zero

Comment: So what would now the formula be, please ? I cant really follow, and I dont want to use matrices.

Comment: new $z=-\sin(angleY)\cdot x+\cos(angleY)\cdot\sin(angleX)\cdot y+\cos(angleY)\cdot\cos(angleX)\cdot z$

Comment: nice ! the new z is correct !